# pip install new Python package to all existing virtualenvs

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am installing a new Python package using pip. I want to install this package in all my current virtual environments in one command. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Currently, when I want to install a new Python package "xyz" in a virtual environment, I activate that venv and then use the standard pip install "xyz" at the command line. However, this only installs it in the currently activated virtual environment. Of course this is big part of having virtual environments in the first place.

If I want to install package "xyz" in all my virtual environments, I have to activate-install-deactivate for each of my environments.

I'd like to avoid this safe but laborious process and simply install a new package "xyz" to all my current virtual environments with a single command.

For example:
I list my existing virtual environments (on my local machine):

λ conda env list

conda environments:

base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
cntk                     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\cntk
fastai                   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\fastai

The package I want to install in all my environments (base, cntk, fastai) is pydicom.

λ activate base

(base) λ pip install pydicom

(base) λ ipython
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pydicom
In [2]:

(base) λ conda deactivate

λ activate cntk

(cntk) λ ipython

Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pydicom

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import pydicom

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydicom'

In [2]:

---

This is all good, venv is doing its job.

---

λ conda activate cntk

(cntk) λ pip install pydicom

Collecting pydicom
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/88/d3c419ab2e753e7651510882a53219373e78fb55294cb247dffd3934ea55/pydicom-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pydicom
Successfully installed pydicom-1.2.2

(cntk) λ ipython

Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pydicom

In [2]:

---

It obviously worked this time since I install pydicom within the venv.

---

Ideally, there would be a command like:
$pip install -- ,

or

$pip install -- all

which installs  to the provided list of venv or all available venvs.

---

I was thinking of workarounds like using $conda env list and then parsing the output. Using a simple script to sequentially install into each of the listed venvs. This thought train brings me to my sub-question:

Q: Is is possible to install a Python package to a virtual environment, without first activating that venv?

---

I doubt there is a simple single line solution (although that would be great), so suggestions for workarounds are welcome.

Admonitions are also welcome, if my intent of automatically installing a new Python package to all venvs is not consistent with best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [virtualenvwrapper](/questions/tagged/virtualenvwrapper) and it has a command `allvirtualenv` so I can run

```
allvirtualenv pip install -U pip setuptools
```

I even update all virtual environments created by [tox](/questions/tagged/tox) in `~/.tox`. My entire script `run-all-venv` is

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

eval "$@"

if source virtualenvwrapper.sh; then
   allvirtualenv eval "$@"

   for tox_envs in ~/.tox/*; do
      if [[ "$tox_envs" = */.tox/\* ]]; then
         exit 0
      fi
      WORKON_HOME="$tox_envs" allvirtualenv eval "$@"
   done
fi
```

and I run it as

```
run-all-venv pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 3):

"Activation" isn't magic, it just prepends the virtualenv executables location to your path and changes your prompt. If you want to install something into a virtualenv without activating it you can just do:

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip install foo
```

As for installing to all virtual environments, I don't think there's any automatic way to do that, specially since envs can live anywhere so you'd need a way to discover them as well. But you can combine the above command with a list of env locations pretty easily if you want to.

Comment: On Windows, the equivalent to bin seems to be Scripts, so: /path/to/virtualenv/Scripts/pip install foo